# How do I convert a string of format dd/mm/yy into datetime in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have table named `PTBV` with two columns: `Dateptbv varchar(50)` and `[Column 1] varchar(50)`.

I'm trying to use the `CONVERT()` function to get actual datetime values from the string data stored in the `Dateptbv` column.

Here are examples of the data in that column:

```
"10/01/13"
"11/01/13"
"14/01/13"
"15/01/13"
"16/01/13"
"17/01/13"
"18/01/13"
"21/01/13"
"22/01/13"
"24/01/13"
"25/01/13"
"28/01/13"
"29/01/13"
"30/01/13"
"01/02/13"
"04/02/13"
```

Note that the quotation marks in this sample *are* part of the data and are stored in the column. Otherwise, data is stored in `dd/mm/yy` format.

Unfortunately, every date style I've tried has resulted in an error message. How can I convert this data into `DateTime` values?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: MS SQL! ok I won't next time, thanks for the advice

Comment: in image its already in date format ? what you actualy want.add expected output here

Comment: It's considered very rude here to post an image, instead of the text for the actual data. It makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your picture correctly, your column `Dateptbv` is `VARCHAR(50)` and stores the date as `yy/mm/dd` wrapped in `"` characters. First of all: **Change this, if ever possible!**. Try to store values in appropriately typed columns!

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(Dateptbv,2,8)),3) --3 for dd/mm/yy
```

Read [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to find more details about the abilities of `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script

```
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(Dateptbv,2,8)  AS DATE)
FROM    PTBV
```

Comment: I get this answer: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2µ
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: This is culture depending and therefore dangerous. One should **never** rely on implicit casts when date or time values are involved!

Comment: @RobinHocepied Your system is - quite probably - by default expecting a different format. That's exactly what I meant in my comment...